# Omitting column when select/find model

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I have some questions about my model:

```
type MaterieprimeAnalisi struct {
    GUIDAnalisiMP      string             `gorm:"size:50;not_null;primary_key;"`
    GUIDMP             null.String        `gorm:"size:50;"`
    Materieprime       Materieprime       `gorm:"foreignkey:GUIDMP;associationforeignkey:GUIDMP;"`
    GUIDPA             null.String        `gorm:"size:50;"`
    Parametrianalitici Parametrianalitici `gorm:"foreignkey:GUIDPA;associationforeignkey:GUIDPA;"`
    Valore             null.Float
}
```

The associations and the foreignkeys works fine, when I `db.AutoMigrate()` this table and the related ones are being created as expected.
My question is, how can I exclude some fields when I directly select all the rows:

```
var ma []models.MaterieprimeAnalisi
res := db.Find(&ma)
```

Or when I join it with another table:

```
var ma []models.MaterieprimeAnalisi
res := db.Joins("Parametrianalitici").Find(&ma)
```

If, for example, I would like to omit `Materieprime` or `Parametrianalitici` from the output result how could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GORM documentation is often poor. There are three ways you can accomplish omitting columns in your query. The first is by using the `tx.Omit` function.

```
var ma []models.MaterieprimeAnalisi
_ := db.Omit("Materieprime", "Parametrianalitici").Find(&ma)
```

You will never find this function in the examples on the website, however. The recommended way in GORM 2.0 is by using `tx.Select` or using the Smart Select feature.

`tx.Select` can be used just as you imagine:

```
var ma []models.MaterieprimeAnalisi
_ := db.Select("GUIDAnalisiMP", "GUIDMP", "GUIDPA", "Valore").Find(&ma)
```

As for `Smart Select`, you can create a partial struct which contains only the fields you want:

```
type MaterieprimeAnalisiSubset struct {
    GUIDAnalisiMP      string            
    GUIDMP             null.String          
    GUIDPA             null.String 
    Valore             null.Float
}
var ma []MaterieprimeAnalisiSubset
tx.Model(&models.MaterieprimeAnalisi{}).Find(&ma)
```

Documentation: [Omit](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Omit), [Select](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Select), [Smart Select](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields)